# when keypad is open to type text screen jumps on android 2.3.4

Tags: cordova, iscroll4

iScroll version being used: 4.1.3

Android Test Device: Sony Ericsson 2.3.4 Android Gingerbread

There are a lot of problems which happen when the keypad is open. Namely

- The screen jumps up and down when the keypad is open
- The screen flickers for dropdowns

what do you suggest??